# Replace pandas column values using time series index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes as:

```
import pandas as pd    
index = pd.date_range('06/01/2014',periods=48,freq='H')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(range(len(index)),index=index)

index2 = pd.date_range('06/02/2014',periods=24,freq='H')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(range(0,24),index=index2)
```

How can I replace the values in `df1` with the values of `df2` by using time series index? I mean whereever index of two data frames match, values of `df1` should get replaced with the values of `df2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) if always `df2.index` is in `df1.index`:

```
df1 = df2.combine_first(df1)
```

But if not, it is a bit complicated - add [`intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html) and then use `combine_first`:

```
index = pd.date_range('06/01/2014',periods=12,freq='H')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(index)),index=index)

index2 = pd.date_range('06/01/2014 08:00:00',periods=6,freq='H')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,6),index=index2)
print (df1)
                      0
2014-06-01 00:00:00   0
2014-06-01 01:00:00   1
2014-06-01 02:00:00   2
2014-06-01 03:00:00   3
2014-06-01 04:00:00   4
2014-06-01 05:00:00   5
2014-06-01 06:00:00   6
2014-06-01 07:00:00   7
2014-06-01 08:00:00   8
2014-06-01 09:00:00   9
2014-06-01 10:00:00  10
2014-06-01 11:00:00  11

print (df2)

                     0
2014-06-01 08:00:00  0
2014-06-01 09:00:00  1
2014-06-01 10:00:00  2
2014-06-01 11:00:00  3
2014-06-01 12:00:00  4
2014-06-01 13:00:00  5
```

```
df1 = df2.loc[df2.index.intersection(df1.index)].combine_first(df1)
print (df1)
                       0
2014-06-01 00:00:00  0.0
2014-06-01 01:00:00  1.0
2014-06-01 02:00:00  2.0
2014-06-01 03:00:00  3.0
2014-06-01 04:00:00  4.0
2014-06-01 05:00:00  5.0
2014-06-01 06:00:00  6.0
2014-06-01 07:00:00  7.0
2014-06-01 08:00:00  0.0
2014-06-01 09:00:00  1.0
2014-06-01 10:00:00  2.0
2014-06-01 11:00:00  3.0
```

---

Another solution with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1.loc[df2.index.intersection(df1.index)] = df2
print (df1)
                     0
2014-06-01 00:00:00  0
2014-06-01 01:00:00  1
2014-06-01 02:00:00  2
2014-06-01 03:00:00  3
2014-06-01 04:00:00  4
2014-06-01 05:00:00  5
2014-06-01 06:00:00  6
2014-06-01 07:00:00  7
2014-06-01 08:00:00  0
2014-06-01 09:00:00  1
2014-06-01 10:00:00  2
2014-06-01 11:00:00  3
```

Answer (score 1):

***Note:***  We could use `combine_first` but I don't like converting `dtypes` to `float`... In order to use `combine_first` you need to include `reindex` or `reindex_like`

```
df2.combine_first(df1).reindex_like(df1)
```

Or

```
df2.combine_first(df1).reindex(df1.index)
```

***my preferred solution***

We can use `map` with a `lambda` on a dictionary.  With this I can preserve the integer `dtype` by utilizing the dictionary `get` method which takes a default value when a key doesn't exist.

```
m = df2[0].to_dict()
f = lambda x: m.get(x, df1.at[x, 0])
df1.index.to_series().map(f)
# you can assign this back to `df1` with
# df1[0] = df1.index.to_series().map(f)
```

---

```
2014-06-01 00:00:00     0
2014-06-01 01:00:00     1
2014-06-01 02:00:00     2
2014-06-01 03:00:00     3
2014-06-01 04:00:00     4
2014-06-01 05:00:00     5
2014-06-01 06:00:00     6
2014-06-01 07:00:00     7
2014-06-01 08:00:00     8
2014-06-01 09:00:00     9
2014-06-01 10:00:00    10
2014-06-01 11:00:00    11
2014-06-01 12:00:00    12
2014-06-01 13:00:00    13
2014-06-01 14:00:00    14
2014-06-01 15:00:00    15
2014-06-01 16:00:00    16
2014-06-01 17:00:00    17
2014-06-01 18:00:00    18
2014-06-01 19:00:00    19
2014-06-01 20:00:00    20
2014-06-01 21:00:00    21
2014-06-01 22:00:00    22
2014-06-01 23:00:00    23
2014-06-02 00:00:00     0
2014-06-02 01:00:00     1
2014-06-02 02:00:00     2
2014-06-02 03:00:00     3
2014-06-02 04:00:00     4
2014-06-02 05:00:00     5
2014-06-02 06:00:00     6
2014-06-02 07:00:00     7
2014-06-02 08:00:00     8
2014-06-02 09:00:00     9
2014-06-02 10:00:00    10
2014-06-02 11:00:00    11
2014-06-02 12:00:00    12
2014-06-02 13:00:00    13
2014-06-02 14:00:00    14
2014-06-02 15:00:00    15
2014-06-02 16:00:00    16
2014-06-02 17:00:00    17
2014-06-02 18:00:00    18
2014-06-02 19:00:00    19
2014-06-02 20:00:00    20
2014-06-02 21:00:00    21
2014-06-02 22:00:00    22
2014-06-02 23:00:00    23
Freq: H, dtype: int64
```